# Get the records from previous year from same account ids present at both time periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

I am trying to get count of transactions for years 2019 and 2021 and compare them with corresponding months for the same customers who have been in 2019 and 2021.example - compare users from 2019 jan who are also there in 2021 Jan and count their transactions and then compare them . I have tried to do a self join but I am getting same number of transactions for both the transactions, any help on tweaking or telling where I have written the query wrongly will help me a lot.

```
Select datepart(r2021.transdate, year), datepart(r2021transdate,month)
,Count (r2021.transaction_id)  as transidcount2021
Count (r2019.transaction_id) as transidcount2019

From rewards r2021
Join rewards r2019
On datepart(r2021.transdate, year)=datepart(r2019.transdate, year)+2
And 
datepart(r2021transdate,month) =datepart(r2019transdate,month)
And
R2021.accountid = r2019.accountid
Where 
datepart(r2021.transdate, year) =2021
Group by 1,2
```

Now if I run this I get same values for transcount2019 and transcount2021 for all months in 2021.

Comment: SQL looks correct. Have you checked, what are values for 2019 - may be they are actually same. `select datepart(r2021.transdate, year), datepart(r2021transdate,month) ,Count (r2021.transaction_id) from datepart(r2021.transdate, year)=2019` and see if its really same.

Comment: Yeah , but it's strange how it can be so for all months , I tried to check by using

Comment: Yeah thanks, but it's strange how it can be so for all months , I tried to check by using.      select datepart(r2021.transdate, year), datepart(r.transdate,month) ,Count (r2021.transaction_id) from rewards r where datepart(r.transdate, year)=2019 and  datepart(r.transdate, month)=1 and accountid in (select accountid from rewards where datepart(r2021.transdate, year)=2021 and datepart(r2021.transdate, month)=1) but it's different :( I can't find what's wrong if such simple query

Comment: I think when you join on `r2021.accountid = r2019.accountid `, its causing duplicates and thats why result for your SQL from your comment and question are producing diff result.

Comment: As per a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), sample data and expected results would help diagnose and suggest corrections.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I don't think the question is clear.  How are users with multiple transactions counted?

Answer (score 1):

> compare users from 2019 jan who are also there in 2021 Jan and count their transactions and then compare them

This suggests that you want a table with columns such as:

- month of the year
- users in 2019
- transactions in 2019
- users in 2021
- transactions in 2021
- users in both years
- transactions in both years

That suggests two levels of aggregation:

```
select month,
       count(*) filter (where cnt_2019 > 0) as customers_2019,
       sum(cnt_2019) as transactions_2019,
       count(*) filter (where cnt_2021 > 0) as customers_2021,
       sum(cnt_2021) as transactions_2021,
       count(*) filter (where cnt_2019 > 0 and cnt_2021 > 0) as customers_both,
       sum(cnt_2019 + cnt_2021) filter (where cnt_2019 > 0 and cnt_2021 > 0) as transactions_both
from (select accountid, extract(month from trandate) as month,
             count(*) filter (where extract(year from trandate) = 2019) as cnt_2019,
             count(*) filter (where extract(year from trandate) = 2021) as cnt_2021
      from rewards r
      group by accountid, month
     ) am
group by month;
```

Comment: Thank you! But only thing is that i would need to get the union of users each month and get their values.